# wso2am-2.2.0 java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [B

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Installing WSO2AM 2.2.0 after startup I see following error in the wso2carbon.log

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.internal.LCMServiceComponent} -  An error occurred
 while setting up Governance Life Cycle Management {org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.internal.LCMServiceComponent}
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [B
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.util.CommonUtil.generateAspect(CommonUtil.java:370)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.util.CommonUtil.addDefaultLifecyclesIfNotAvailable(CommonUtil.java:534)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.internal.LCMServiceComponent.setRegistryService(LCMServiceComponent.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at 

org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218)
```

the same message `[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [B` I receive when trying to login into the publisher console (it looks like something wants to cast a string to a byte array). I still can login into carbon console and I don't see any other error mesasge in the wso2carbon.log (that is strange..)

Setup - there are 2 wso2am nodes with shared databases, filesystem and wka clustering.

Note: I haven't see nthis exception on the wummed version yet